# Google Charts GeoChart Markers Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I have been trying to follow along with the Google Charts documentation for GeoCharts. For some reason, whenever I try to run their code for [markers](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#marker-geocharts) on my local host it only returns a blank map of Italy. I have created my own Google Maps JS API key and am using that instead of the one provided but it still returns nothing. I'm very lost as I have not been able to find anything that can guide me to the right direction. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     google.charts.load('current', {
       'packages': ['geochart'],
       // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
       // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
       'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY' //used my own API key instead of theirs
     });
     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

      function drawMarkersMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['City',   'Population', 'Area'],
        ['Rome',      2761477,    1285.31],
        ['Milan',     1324110,    181.76],
        ['Naples',    959574,     117.27],
        ['Turin',     907563,     130.17],
        ['Palermo',   655875,     158.9],
        ['Genoa',     607906,     243.60],
        ['Bologna',   380181,     140.7],
        ['Florence',  371282,     102.41],
        ['Fiumicino', 67370,      213.44],
        ['Anzio',     52192,      43.43],
        ['Ciampino',  38262,      11]
      ]);

      var options = {
        region: 'IT',
        displayMode: 'markers',
        colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please check the browser's console (press F12) and report any errors...